# Can you reference properties within other properties in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a ScrollBar whose Maximum property binds to a dependency object, and I want the LargeChange and SmallChange properties to always be constant fractions of this length.  I currently implement this in the code-behind but am trying to switch to an all-XAML approach.

So instead of this:

```
curSpeedScrollbar.SetBinding(Slider.MaximumProperty, speedBinding);
curSpeedScrollbar.LargeChange = curSpeedScrollbar.Maximum / 1000;
curSpeedScrollbar.SmallChange = curSpeedScrollbar.Maximum / 10000;
curSpeedScrollbar.ViewportSize = curSpeedScrollbar.Maximum / 16;
```

I'm shooting for something like this (but with the correct syntax):

```
<ScrollBar BorderThickness="1" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" LargeChange = "Maximum / 1000" Margin="208,62,130,106" Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}" Name="curSpeedScrollbar" Orientation="Horizontal" SmallChange = "Maximum / 10000" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ViewportSize="Maximum / 16" Width="431" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Can anyone show me the proper syntax to do this?  Or if there is a better way to achieve what I want (no/minimal code-behind, all/mostly in XAML)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to your question, so I will respond to each of them individually:

**How to bind to a property from within a property**

This is possible, and in fact, it is constantly done - bindings are (almost) always added from a property to refer to another property. Normally, you just do not refer to another property of the same object, but this can be done with [`RelativeSourceMode.Self`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
LargeChange="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

**How to bind to a multiplied value of a property**

For this, you will have to create a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). A very static version of such a converter could look like this:

```
public class DividingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value) / 1000;
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You may have to check `value` for [`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as sometimes, dependency properties are unset at some point.

For a more dynamic version, you can use the [`ConverterParameter` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from bindings to supply the value to divide by.

This converter can then be added as a static resource in your XAML:

```
<somewhere:DividingConverter x:Key="divConv"/>
```

(where `somewhere` is a namespace prefix for your converter namespace)

It can then be used in bindings such as the above one:

```
LargeChange="{Binding Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource divConv}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples and links.  This essentially became an intro to value converters for me.  Very useful!

Comment: @reservoirman: I have edited my answer to mention `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, as that can become an unnecessary source of issues if you're new to value converters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a converter to achieve this behavior.

A math converter for these operations can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239251/MathConverter-How-to-Do-Math-in-XAML

Answer (score 1):

To just bind some property to the value of another property of the same control, you can use `RelativeSource.Self`:

```
<ScrollBar Maximum="{Binding MaxValue}" SmallChange="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Maximum}" ... />
```

This would set `SmallChange` to the same value as `Maximum`.

However, this is as far as you get, since calculations are not possible directly within XAML. For this you'd need a converter that, for example, takes the `Maximum` property's value as input and returns the calculation's result.